# Is there a way for code competition in Php for IDE's in case of "mixed" types?

Tags: php

Lets check a `Factory` class. It can return any class, or it at least one fix class. Code competitions cant know its methods/properties, how to "tell" to IDE's its class?

Comment: Did you mean code completion? There's no way of telling object of which class is returned by a factory without executing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PHPDoc, most IDEs support it.

```
/**
 * Factory::make()
 * 
 * @param string $classname
 *
 * @return Object - The object being made.
 */
```